# Require Angular js directive for JQUERY PTTIMESELECT Timepicker plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

Could you please help me in having this angular directive corrected for Jquery pttimeselect timepicker plugin.

http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/doc/documentation.html

Plunker link:
http://tinyurl.com/hr7lker

Currently i have directive as below ,but getting this error 
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined**

```
app.directive('timePicker', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict : "C",
        replace : true,
        transclude : false,
        compile : function(element, attrs) {
            var modelAccessor = $parse(attrs.ngModel);

            return function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                var processChange = function(i) {
                    var time = i.val();
                    scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                        modelAccessor.assign(scope, time);
                    });
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
                };
                element.ptTimeSelect({
                    onClose : processChange
                });
                scope.$watch(modelAccessor, function(val) {
                    element.val(val);
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your versions of jQuery and Angular, and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pp2Ce9CkEKYLhZtLni6p?p=preview

Comment: Thank you !! so much that helped a lot

Comment: @masa..could you please help on the below error,i have upgraded the Angular to 1.4.8,but still getting this error.am unable to reproduce it in plunker                                                                                                  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openCntr' of undefined(anonymous function) @ jquery.ptTimeSelect.js?v=1448900535634:471m.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4r.handle @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4..I

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/home/common/libs/latest/js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js?v=1448900535634:456:60)    at Function.m.extend.each (http://localhost:8080/home/common/libs/vendor/jquery/1.11.3/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:2975)
    at m.fn.m.each...jquery file ...  at jQuery.fn.ptTimeSelect (http://localhost:8080/home/common/libs/js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js?v=1448900535634:449:21)    at http://localhost:8080/home/js/common/app.js?v=1448900535634:374:13

Comment: Sorry, I would need more info (preferably a plunker) to be able to say what goes wrong in here.